# OxyPlot InvalidatePlot does not work on recyclerview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, oxyplot

I am using mvvmcross and binding oxyplot as follows, but refreshing plot with `InvalidatePlot` does not work.

**xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <oxyplot.xamarin.android.PlotView
         android:id="@+id/chart_data"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         local:MvxBind="Model PlotModel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ClassroomViewRecyclerAdapter.cs**

```
public class ClassroomViewRecyclerAdapter: MvxRecyclerAdapter
{
    private readonly FragmentActivity _activity;
    private readonly IMvxAndroidBindingContext _bindingContext;
    public PlotView cardPlotView ;

   public ClassroomViewRecyclerAdapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext, FragmentActivity activity)
        : base(bindingContext)
   {
        _activity = activity;
        _bindingContext = bindingContext;
   }
   public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
   {
     base.OnBindViewHolder(holder, position);
     var view = holder.ItemView;
     cardPlotView = view.FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id.chart_data);
     cardPlotView.InvalidatePlot(true);
   }
}
```